# Image of a constant map

Tags: functions

Say I have a constant map $ f = -1.$

If I choose the domain ($X$) and the range ($Y$) such that $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, what is the **image** of the $f$? 
I.e. what is the subset of $Y$ such that all its elements are $=f(x)$?

Is it just $-1$, or does it not exist since choosing $x$ has no effect on the value of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is defined as all values that $f$ can reach. In this case, $\text{im}(f) = \{-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=-1$, the range of $f$ is of course $\{-1\}$ !